# Function called after render react native

Tags: listview, react-native, components, delay, rerender

i have a load function which loads my data to my ListView datasource and as you might know ListView wont always rerender with changing state and i need to forceupdate it this load function works really well being called by a button but i want it to auto load but calling forceupdate is not available in componentwill/did mount functions what can i do ? i just want my function to be called with a little delay after render. the problem is this.props.navigation is not an object before render and cant be used in componentwill/did mount.

```
 //   UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
//   this.makeScene();
// }

makeScene(){
var count = Object.keys(window.contents[this.props.navigation.getParam('name')]).length;
for(let i = 0 ; i < count ; i ++){
  global.subnum[i] = i;
  global.lowersubjects[i] = window.contents[this.props.navigation.getParam('name')][i].subject;
  global.lowerdescriptions[i] = window.contents[this.props.navigation.getParam('name')][i].description;
  global.lowerimageurl[i] = window.contents[this.props.navigation.getParam('name')][i].imageurl;
  global.author[i] = window.contents[this.props.navigation.getParam('name')][i].author;
  global.eventdate[i] = window.contents[this.props.navigation.getParam('name')][i].eventdate;
}
this.setState({
  subnum : global.subnum
});
this.forceUpdate();
}
```

uncommenting will cause my app buttons and render stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 things:

Firstable, getParam is missing an argument that is a default value if the specified field is empty or do not exists :

`var name = this.props.navigation.getParam('name', 'defaultName')`

With name you won't have to call it all time to access your array cell.

Second, What is you window.contents ?

Finaly, every this.setState() call will cause the view to render IF the state or props of your component has changed. You should call your procedure in `componentDidMount()` and yes, `this.props.navigation` should be accessible into `componentDidMount()` since your component is in a navigator I suppose...

Comment: the problem with componentdidmount is it gets called when my app launchs not when i navigate to the page i want it to be called when the page is rendered because the window.contents which is a global variable gets filled in the previous page and ill get undefined if this gets called before i navigate to the page ( i use stacknavigator ) and thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: componentDidMount should get called on mounting the Component, not when the app start. If your datasource is hold within the state your ListView will re-render. You could also try to call `this.makeScene()` in the constructor. If you try to use some of the data you are "generating" in the makeScene function you might get an error if it is not done before the ListView tries to render it.

Comment: @howtopythonpls i dont know why but when i use stacknavigator componentdidmount gets called when i move to the first page of my stacknavigator (without moving to the page i called componentdidmount on ) and i found other people had this issue too. but thanks anyway i could just fix it with calling componentwillmount which gets called on the start and when i navigate to the page and added a if condition so my function will only get called when the window.content is ready and not empty.

Comment: Okey did you console.log inside of your componentDidMount to confirm that this is the case (because that's weird)? I had a similar problem where both the constructor and componentDidMount was called when I left the page, had to fix this with a condition just as you did.

Comment: @BehnamAminazad Yes, when you create a Navigator, it will mount all the components it contains at once when rendering the Navigator, that's normal behavior. In your `componentDidMount()`, or even better, in your `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`, check if you have data you need or else set a default value that won't crash your view (don't forget that this method has to returns a bool)